# Прием данных из jquery в php

Tags: jquery, php, html

Добрый вечер. У меня есть небольшая форма заказа обратного звонка:

```
                <form action="#" method="post" id="discover_price" onsubmit="return checkForm('discover_price');">
                <div class="forma">
                        <span>Ваше имя *</span>
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                        <span>Ваш телефон для связи *</span>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" />                      
                        <div class="bt" onclick="$('#discover_price').submit();">Отправить</div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

И я написал вот такой вот скрипт для того чтобы jquery принял данные проверил на пустоту полей и потом передал в php эти же данные для отправки на email и после успешной отправки вернул бы сообщение в окошке alert что сообщение отправлено.

```
 function checkForm(form_id)
{
    name = document.forms[form_id]["name"].value;
    phone = document.forms[form_id]["phone"].value;
    bot_name = document.forms["write_review"]["main"].value;

    if(bot_name == '')
    {
        if(name == '' || phone == '')
        {
            alert('Заполните обязательные поля');
            return false;
        } else {
            $.post("eblan.php",
            {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                bot_name: bot_name
            },
            function(data){
                alert(data);
            }   
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Но где то происходит косяк и форма не отправляется... Прошу вашей помощи как реализовать сие чудо? Необходимо именно реализовать через данный скрипт который я написал, ну если такое возможно :) 
php скрипт напрямую нормально отправляет сообщение на емейл.

Comment: 1) перед `$.post()` вывести все поля, проверить на корректность

2) в `eblan.php` вывести в лог `$_POST`, да и вообще последовательно всё, что на пути от разбора поста до анализа результата отправки. анализ результата - тоже.

3) внимательно читать, думать (лучше до 1 и 2):  http://www.phpfaq.ru/debug

4) BTW, зачем в пост уходит `bot_name`, если оно по условию - пустое?

Comment: А ещё есть IDE с пошаговой отладкой, если вы понимаете, о чём я ;)

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, да вариантов - тыща :) Только ими никто не хочет пользоваться, проще же написать что-то не думая, а потом пусть общественность ищет что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо $.post запиши так:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "eblan.php",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                bot_name: bot_name
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: и еще: сам else срабативает ?

Comment: @crymaks, сам else срабатывает, проверял путем вывода в alert просто переменной после else. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: почему так?

Comment: @crymaks, сообщение отправляется! Спасибо огромное! Вот только не вылетает сообщение alert после успешной отправки. Сообщение нормально приходит. 
Вот так у меня прописаны последние строчки php скрипта:

   mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
   
   echo "Сообщение отправлено";

Мб стоит написать не echo ? 
Пробовал писать return сообщение вообще не отправляется. С echo сообщение приходит на емейл.

Comment: @KeH192 ну в конце файла отправки стоить еще die(); прописать.
Должно возвращать значение, проверь в firebag, есть ли возврат.

Если нет то просто впиши его в alert();

Comment: @crymaks, провозился целый день, но так и не удалось заставить вернуть успешную отправку из php в аякс. Прописал как вы и говорили в конце php файла die(); но все равно сообщение alert не вылетает. в чем может быть ошибка? 
В php файле у меня всего лишь стандартная функция mail.

Answer (score 1):

> > > bot_name = document.forms["write_review"]["main"].value;

Это мешает отправить форму

> > > Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Попытка чтения атрибута несуществующего объекта

Comment: Хотя такая форма конечно может быть на странице, но в постановке вопроса отсутствует

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, данная форма существует на странице, просто я её не указывал в данном вопросе.